# Reading data from txt file

Tags: python

```
def main():
    file_output=open(r'C:\Users\P\Desktop\randominput.txt','r')

    for num in file_output:
        number=file_output.read()
        print(number)
main()
```

output:

```
48
85
58
16
11
82
```

Actual data in the txt file is

```
53
48
85
58
16
11
82
```

Why is my python program not reading the first number??

Comment: Why are you iterating over the file, then using `read` inside the loop? Also, what is the content of the file?

Comment: Whats the structure of the txt file? are the numbers separated by lines?

Comment: yes they are seperated by '/n'

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple **print** to trace what's going on:

```
for num in file_output:
    print("num=", num)
    number=file_output.read()
    print(number)
```

Output:

```
num= 53

48
85
58
16
11
82
```

Note the effect: **num** is the first input number, but it appears only once.  You go through the loop only once.

Your **for** loop grabs the first number out of the file; the **read** within the loop grabs the remainder of the file as one input.

I suggest that you look up that actual function of each command you're using; you're not *quite* clear on the operation yet.

---

**REPAIR**

```
def main():
    with open("so.txt") as file_output:

        for num in file_output:
            print("num=", num)
main()
```

Output:

```
num= 53

num= 48

num= 85

num= 58

num= 16

num= 11

num= 82
```

Note that you're still reading these as strings, complete with newline character.  Continuing from here is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the file is consumed during the first iteration of the for loop.  The `read()` then reads the file from the current position in the file, which is the beginning of the second line, to the end of the file.

So the `print()` is printing the contents of the file in one go, having skipped over the first line.

To fix your code:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\P\Desktop\randominput.txt', 'r') as file_input:
    for number in file_input:
        print(number.rstrip())
```

The `rstrip()` is there to remove the new line character at the end of each line. Also the file is opened in a context manager using `with`. This will ensure that the file will be closed in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

is it a typo that in the "open(r'C:\Users\P\Desktop\randominput.txt','r')" there is an r before 'C\Users\P...'? that shouldn't be there.

I believe you are trying to print every number from a text file. here is a way you could do this:

```
f = open("C:/Users/u/file.txt")
file_contents = f.read()
numbers = str(file_contents).split()
for x in range (0, len(numbers) - 1):
    print (str(numbers[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program *is* reading the first number.  When you begin iterating over the file object, `for num in file_output:` the first line of the file is read, so `num` is the first number and the file reader is now looking at the second, waiting for the next iteration.

You then call `.read()` which will read to the end of the file.  This gives you all the rest of the numbers in `number` and moves the reader to the end of the file, terminating the iteration.  You want either:

```
for num in file_output:
    print(num)
```

or

```
numbers = file_output.read()
for n in numbers:
    print(n)
```